# JSDoc describe object values only

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

Say I've object like that:

```
const Companies = {Mazda : {revenue:50000, employees:1000},
Honda: {revenue: 102324, employees:2031}}
```

And this function:

```
const totalRevenue = (companies) => 
Object.values(companies)
.map(companyObject => companyObject.revenue)
.reduce((total, companyRevenue)=> total + companyRevenue)
```

How do I use JSDoc to tell the function 
`totalRevenue` that the `companies` object is an object that every key it has, has a value of the kind `{revenue: Number, employees: Number}`

I'm specifically interested in something that WebStorm will understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can describe every key in object with the `{Object.<string, number>}` notation. see more syntax examples here: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

for your specific scenario:

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, {revenue: number, employees: number}>} companies
 */
const totalRevenue = (companies) => 
Object.values(companies)
.map(companyObject => companyObject.revenue)
.reduce((total, companyRevenue)=> total + companyRevenue)
```

Comment: Wow exactly what I was looking for !